# After editing the CSS of a page using Chrome Dev Tools, can I view the specific changes I've made?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am aware that there are ways to save my local overrides in Chrome Dev Tools, but what I'm really looking for is the ability to keep track of what changes I just made to the DOM so that I can then apply those changes to my source code since I will never again remember which of those classes I've modified or how in order to get this amazingly beautiful div to center horizontally of course.

All I want is just the list of things I've done in the Elements tab that override the page. I don't need it to persist across refreshes, I just need to see the list of what I did.